ggplot2 text in top margin, flipped coordinates
I would like to add some text to a plot in the top margin, but all the solutions I could find messed up the flipped coordinate system after using coord_flip()
var1<- c("ab", "cd")
HR1<-c (0.51, 0.65)
lower1 <- c(0.4, 0.5)
upper1 <- c(0.6, 0.9)
forest1 <- data.frame(var1, HR1, lower1, upper1)
ggplot(data=forest1, aes(x=var1, y=HR1, ymin=lower1, ymax=upper1)) +
  geom_pointrange() +
  geom_hline(yintercept=1, lty=2) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0.4, lty=2) +  
  coord_flip() +  
  xlab("Label") + ylab("Mean (95% CI)") +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x="", y="HR") + ylim(0.3, 1.1) +
  theme(plot.margin = unit(c(4, 1, 1, 1), "lines")) 

It should be like in the image.
Is there a (simple) solution?
Thanks!

var1 is missing from your code. Please recheck all of your code to ensure it is correct, and update where necessary. Thanks.

An easy option to achieve your desired result would be to add your annotations using the secondary axis trick, i.e. add a secondary x axis and add your annotations via the axis text. And if you need some additional styling you could do so using e.g. ggtext.
Note: I dropped the coord_flip and instead switched x and y.
library(ggplot2)
library(ggtext)

ggplot(data = forest1, aes(y = var1, x = HR1, xmin = lower1, xmax = upper1)) +
  geom_pointrange() +
  geom_vline(xintercept = c(.4, 1), lty = 2) +
  scale_x_continuous(
    sec.axis = dup_axis(
      breaks = c(.325, .6, 1.075),
      labels = c("Words", "Words", "**More Words**")
    ),
    limits = c(0.3, 1.1)
  ) +
  theme_bw() +
  labs(x = NULL, y = "HR") +
  theme(
    axis.text.x.top = ggtext::element_markdown(size = 12),
    axis.ticks.x.top = element_blank()
  )


